# How to do pagination of table with xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to keep two rows together, without page break happening between them. My xslt script is as follow:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:xs=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform>

  <xsl:template priority="101" match="row[.//entry[@nameend='c2']/ph]">
    <xsl:call-template name="row-keep-with-next"/>
  </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template name="row-keep-with-next">
    <xsl:variable name="row" as="node()">
      <topic class="- topic/tbody "> 
        <xsl:copy >
          <xsl:sequence select="@* except @outputclass"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="outputclass" select="string-join(('keep-with-next', tokenize(@outputclass, '\s+')), ' ')"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </topic>
    </xsl:variable>
   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$row"/> 
  </xsl:template>
 
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I still see page break happening. My css is as follows:

```
@media print 
    { *[outputclass~="keep-with-next"] { page-break-after: avoid; } 
*[outputclass~="keep-with-previous"] { page-break-before: avoid; } 
*[outputclass~="top-of-page"] { page-break-before: always; } }
```

This is the sample on which I am trying to test:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE dita
    
      PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Composite//EN" "dtd/ditabase.dtd">
    
    <dita><!-- topic/titlealts  not supplied within  topic/topic --><!-- topic/prolog  not supplied within  topic/topic --><reference xmlns:ditaarch=http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/ id="parameters_top"><title>Parts</title>
    
    <refbody outputclass="db.sect2"><section>
<table id="paratable" pgwide="1" outputclass="PTable"><title outputclass="db.title">Basic Config</title>
<tgroup cols="2" outputclass="ParametersTable"><colspec colnum="1" colname="c1" colwidth="2*"/><colspec colnum="2" colname="c2" colwidth="5*"/>

<thead outputclass="db.thead"><row outputclass="db.row"><entry outputclass="db.entry">Label</entry><entry outputclass="db.entry">Description</entry></row></thead>

<tbody outputclass="db.tbody">
    
<row outputclass="db.row"><entry outputclass="db.entry" namest="c1" nameend="c2" align="center"><ph outputclass="db.phrase"> P Type </ph></entry></row>
    
    <row outputclass="db.row"><entry outputclass="db.entry"><ph outputclass="db.phrase">Phy</ph></entry><entry outputclass="db.entry"><p outputclass="db.para"><ph outputclass="db.phrase">Select the type of PHY.</ph></p></entry></row>
    
    <row outputclass="db.row"><entry outputclass="db.entry"><ph outputclass="db.phrase">Speed</ph></entry><entry outputclass="db.entry"><p outputclass="db.para">Link speed </p></entry></row></tbody></table></section></refbody></reference></dita>
```

I am trying to avoid pagebreak after row with "P Type".

Comment: 1. <xsl:copy select="."> the select is 3.0. Just use  <xsl:copy>...but that will copy your context and that is the row.
And it looks like you create a infinite loop. by <xsl:apply-templates select="$row/*"/> where the * is the row again.?

Comment: It is row again. This solution is not working @SiebeJongebloed

Comment: Correct. Your $row is a topic now so use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$row"/>` and handle that somehow

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed this still does not avoid pagebreak.

Comment: Then you have to edit your question in a way we can reproduce your problem.  So share more xslt-code , a minimal xml source example and the expected outcome

Comment: I have modified the question as I am using it.

Comment: And the source- and expected result-xml?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Your xml is not wellformed

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I just reformed it.